# Count the number of entries in BST with key k in time O(h)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, big-o, binary-search-tree

I had a exam last week and I faced the following question:

> Describe how you would modify the binary search tree to count the
>   number of entries in T with key k in O(h) time. This algorithm should return an
>   integer, not a list.

then after the exam the answer was published and it is as follow:

Solution: Modify the tree by adding, to each node, the number of internal nodes in the
subtree rooted at that node. Recalculate these when nodes are inserted, removed,
and potentially restructured. This would need the following algorithm:

[image]

But it seems very confusing. My question is what is the role of those parts that I circled them with red?

Comment: Was the structure of a node in the tree specified anywhere in the exam? `count` seems to be a variable associated with each node, but it isn't defined anywhere in this algorithm.

Comment: Sorry O(h) is right I mean big O

Comment: No this what I had in the exam and I can not understand it

Comment: The title says o(h), the question says O(h). While they have nothing to do with what you would like to know, I wanted to remark that those are different sets. Other than that. `T.left.right` and `T.right.left` in those two cases are known to hold only the value you are looking for due to the sorting of the search tree. You know that if `T.left.value == k`, then since for the stored values you have `T.left <= T <= T.right`, that `T.left.value <= T.left.right <= T.value` and since `T.left.value == T.value`, the inequality collapses to an equality for `T.left.right`; the other one analogously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you find a node `node` with value `k`, which is what you're searching for.  Now, suppose `node.left.value = k`. What do you know about everything in the subtree `node.left.right`?  Every value there must be less than or equal to `k` (because it's to the left of `node`) but also greater than or equal to `k` (because it's to the right of `node.left`).  Therefore, all the values in that subtrees are equal to `k`.  The algorithm, as an optimization, avoids recursively descending into that subtree in that case and instead just automatically adds everything in that subtree to the total.  This is necessary to get the O(h) runtime; if you explored all the nodes in those trees, the runtime might be Ω(n) if all n values in the tree are equal to `k`.

Similar logic applies for `node.right.left` in the case where `node.right.value = k`.

Hope this helps!